# awk: cmd. line:1: { print \$9} : syntax error

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I am trying to run the following command to get the "gis" & "cpu" usage from shell script. However when i try to run this command even manually, then i am getting the below error.

Any senior/expert please help on this.

```
$ top -b | head -n 8 | grep -w gis | awk '{ print \$9}'
awk: cmd. line:1: { print \$9}
awk: cmd. line:1:         ^ backslash not last character on line
awk: cmd. line:1: { print \$9}
awk: cmd. line:1:         ^ syntax error

$ top -b | head -n 8 | grep -w gis | awk '{ print \$10}'

# Same error i am getting for second command as well.
```

Comment: As the error message tells you, the backslash is the problem. `$` must not be escaped here, it's already in single quotes and protected from expansion by the shell.

Comment: And the `head | grep | awk` is a [useless use of `grep`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep) and `head` too.  Trivially, `top -b | awk '/\<gis\>/ { print $9 } NR==8 { exit 0 }'` but you would probably be even better off not parsing the output from `top` and fishing the information you need out of the `/proc` filesystem instead if your OS has something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to escape the $. You are using single quotes, so the shell won't interpolate the $9. If you were using double quotes, you would need to escape it.

So, you have to...

```
top -b | head -n 8 | grep -w gis | awk '{ print $9}'
```

or

```
top -b | head -n 8 | grep -w gis | awk "{ print \$9}"
```

Comment: Good points, but it's also worth mentioning that using double-quoted strings to represent `awk` scripts is ill-advised, given that `$` has special meaning there as well.